# Não consigo comparar char[]

Tags: c, socket, char

Estou executando um servidor que fiz em C e está funcionando normalmente, com apenas uma exceção: Não consigo criar uma condição pros bytes recebidos. A função Write e Recv funcionam normalmente mas estou caindo em um erro bobo na qual a cláusula Else é sempre ativada. Configurei o meu cliente para ASCII mas não obtive êxito.

Imagem:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está utilizando o operador lógico `==` para comparar `responseLogin` com `"ADMIN"`. O que está ocorrendo, de fato, aí é a comparação dos endereços de memória das matrizes  `responseLogin` e `"ADMIN"`. Dessa forma, como os ponteiros são distintos, a condição é sempre falsa.

Para atingir o que você realmente quer, ou seja, comparar o **conteúdo** das matrizes de caracteres, você deve usar uma função como a [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/). Observe:

```
char *responseLogin = "ADMIN"; 

if (responseLogin == "ADMIN") // condição falsa, os ponteiros comparados são diferentes
{
    // ...
}

if (strcmp(responseLogin, "ADMIN") == 0) // condição verdadeira, os conteúdos são iguais
{
    // ...
}
```